# Translation of "memoir"

Tags: traduction

What is the translation of [memoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoir) (a collection of memories that an individual writes about moments or events, both public or private, that took place in the subject's life)?

An English-French [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/memoir) gives the straightforward translation *le mémoire*, but looking up [*le mémoire*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/m%C3%A9moire) yields the translations

> 1. memorandum
> 2. dissertation, paper

neither of which corresponds to the English "memoir".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the plural "mémoires". Another dictionary seems to have it right, [here](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/memoirs). Here is a [dictionary](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%A9moires/50403?q=m%C3%A9moires) with the definition of "mémoires" in French.

Examples are: les Mémoires de Saint-Simon, les Mémoires de Vidocq.