# Mémoire(s), mémorial : différences de sens et d'emploi ?

Tags: sens, usage, genre, majuscules

Comme nous le rappelle une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23217), on peut avoir *un [mémoire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9moire/1)* au masculin pour la « relation manuscrite ou imprimée qui rappelle la vie, les événements auxquels est associée une personne », et en particulier au pluriel pour la « relation, parfois œuvre littéraire, que fait une personne à partir d'événements historiques ou privés auxquels elle a participé ou dont elle a été le témoin » (TLFi) :

> Si j'étais destiné à vivre, je représenterais dans ma personne,
>   représentée dans mes mémoires, les principes, les idées, les
>   événements, les catastrophes, l'épopée de mon temps. (Chateaubriand,
>   [*Mémoires d'outre-tombe*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/M%C3%A9moires_d%E2%80%99outre-tombe/Pr%C3%A9face_testamentaire))

On a aussi le *mémorial*, comme celui de [*Pascal*](http://www.jdarriulat.net/Auteurs/Pascal/PascalIntrod5.html) ou de [*Sainte-Hélène*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_M%C3%A9morial_de_Sainte-H%C3%A9l%C3%A8ne) ; généralement le « livre où sont consignés les souvenirs d’une personne » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9morial)). On peut écrire son [*mémorial*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9morial) nous dit-on (TLFi).

Quand il s'agit du titre d'une œuvre, on n'est pas surpris de retrouver la majuscule à *mémoires* ou *mémorial*. Par ailleurs [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%A9moire/50402/difficulte) en ligne présente comme exemple « Publier ses Mémoires » : on est surpris. On a déniché un exemple à mi-chemin, pourrait-on dire, au *LBU14* (§ 510c) : « La trilogie de Fraigneau [...], trois Mémoires apocryphes, [verbe etc.] » (Curtis) où on a aussi [remarqué](https://books.google.com/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA639&dq=%22princi%C3%A8res%20m%C3%A9moires%22%20duchesse%20berry&pg=PA639#v=onepage&q=%22princi%C3%A8res%20m%C3%A9moires%22%20&f=false) des emplois au féminin chez des auteurs réputés comme André Castelot ou Jean Tordeur (voir [ici](http://www.arllfb.be/bulletin/bulletinsnumerises/bulletin_1987_lxv_01.pdf), p.31 :  « [titres] ne constituent pas des mémoires exactes mais une autobiographie romancée [...] » )

---

- Quelle est précisément la **différence** de sens entre le(s) *mémoire(s)* et le *mémorial* et en quoi leurs emplois diffèrent-ils ?
- Peut-on indiquer dans quels cas on a la **majuscule** initiale ?
- L'emploi du **féminin** pluriel (accords avec ce genre) avec *mémoires* (ex. J. Tordeur) est-il en progression et s'explique-t-il autrement que par la familiarité avec le mot au féminin pour la *capacité à se souvenir* (la mémoire) ; y a-t-il généralement des pluriels épicènes alors que le singulier ne le serait pas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Différence ente *les mémoires* et *mémorial*** : L'utilisation la plus fréquente dans la langue française pour définir un recueil de souvenir sera  le terme *mémoires*. Le mot *mémorial* étant quant à lui préféré pour parler d'un monument commémoratif d'une période historique. Cependant il peux aussi être employé pour parler d'un écrit où l'on consigne des événements passés. 
  La différence subtil réside dans le fait que ***des mémoires* sont écrits par la personne qui a vécu ces événements**, ils prennent ainsi une dimension autobiographique, alors qu'un *mémorial* raconte **des événements qui ne sont pas nécessairement liés à l'auteur**.
- **Dans quel cas utiliser la majuscule** : La majuscule s'utilisera lorsque l'on veut indiquer que l'on **cite le titre d'une œuvre littéraire et/ou son auteur**. L'utilisation de la majuscule dans votre premier exemple est possible, du fait de l'utilisation du possesif "ses", qui implique donc l'auteur. Dans le second exemple, on cite directement l'auteur "Fraigneau", d'où l'emploi de la majuscule.
- **Féminisation du terme** : Il n'est pas rare de trouver des variations de la définition, certains le définissant au singulier (*un mémoire*), voire comme dans votre exemple, au féminin. Ceci est en effet dut à l'évolution de la langue et des différentes associations qui peuvent être faites avec des mots proches. Le nom masculin pluriel étant cependant le plus répandu et celui validé par le dictionnaire. Le terme *mémoires* est très particulier, et dans l'ensemble des mots épicènes, je n'ai pu trouver des exemples de mots étant épicène au pluriel et non au singulier.

Comment: Mais le fait d'impliquer un auteur n'implique pas nécessairement qu'il y ait un titre ou même une œuvre en soi ; mais si c'était donc un auteur dont ces écrits portaient le titre _Mémoires_, ne devrait-il pas être au moins en italiques ou entre guillemets p-ê. si l'italique est la norme pour la phrase, ce qui est le cas des exemples au Larousse qui sont toujours en italiques ?? Avec l'exemple où on a Fraigneau, l'association est très concrète. En résumé je trouve étonnant le traitement du mot comme d'un titre pour un auteur abstrait, un générique au final, mais c'est bien intéressant. Merci !

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il y ai vraiment de règle précise à ce point, et qu'il est laissé libre à la personne qui écrit de choisir entre majuscule ou minuscule. Dans l'ensemble des exemples que j'ai pu voir, certains auteurs mettent une majuscule à la première allusion, puis ensuite une minuscule, cela me semble être le choix le plus fréquent.